# Binding View Events in MVP

Tags: .net, delegates, event-handling, mvp

I'm creating an MVP project and I've got most of the pieces in place, but I'm a little confused about a couple of points. Here's my code:

```
//Used to invoke asynchronous calls.
Public Delegate ModelNumberChangedDelegate(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

Public Interface IEquipmentView
    Event ModelNumberChanged as ModelNumberChangedDelegate

    Property ModelNumber as String
End Interface

Public Class Equipment
    Inherits Form
    Implements IEquipmentView

Public Property ModelNumber Implements IEquipmentView.ModelNumber
    Get
        return txtModelNumber.Text //A texbox
    End Get
    Set(value as String)
        txtModelNumber.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Event ModelNumberChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _
    Implements IEquipmentView.ModelNumberChanged

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    AddHandler ModelNumberChanged, AddressOf view_ModelNumberChanged
End Sub   

Private Sub view_ModelNumberChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    //If invoke is required, create a ModelNumberChangedDelegate and invoke it
    //at this address. Otherwise, just execute the method.
End Sub

End Class
```

My confusion lies in how I should actually raise this event. Should I simply go to the property and raise the ModelChangedEvent manually, like this:

```
Public Property ModelNumber Implements IEquipmentView.ModelNumber
    Get
        return txtModelNumber.Text //A texbox
    End Get
    Set(value as String)
        txtModelNumber.Text = value
        RaiseEvent ModelNumberChangedEvent(txtModelNumber, Nothing)
    End Set
End Property
```

Or, should I bind the control's changed event straight to the delegate function, like this:

```
Public Sub view_ModelNumberChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _
    Handles txtModelNumber.Changed
    //If invoke is required, create a ModelNumberChangedDelegate and invoke it
    //at this address. Otherwise, just execute the method.
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Note: I know that the comments are wrong, but if I use `'` in the post, it interprets them as strings.

Comment: notify property can be raised from directly from the model...